# Shipping method Table Rates: Magento (v.1.7) always include tax in Order Subtotal value

Tags: table-rates

I'm having an issue with Magento Table Rates. Magento always adds a tax to the "Order Subtotal". I spend hours to get rid of it and to find the line where Magento is doing this. Unfortunately without success.

My CSV contains for example:

```
Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Order Subtotal (and above)","Shipping Price"
*,*,*,0.0000,14.5000
*,*,*,35.0000,0.0000
```

That means that all orders >= $35 are eligible for free shipping. But only orders >= $42 gets the free shipping options. Its definitely the tax - if I'm going to the checkout page I see $7 tax.

It only works if I set "Order Subtotal" to "29.0000" instead of "35.0000". But that's a bad and only static solution.
Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a solution. Copy file Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php to your local directory and add following code before //Free shipping by qty (around line 78)

```
        if (Mage::helper('tax')->priceIncludesTax()) {
        $taxableAmount = 0;
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $taxableAmount += $item->getTaxableAmount();
        }
        $request->setPackageValue($taxableAmount);
    }
```

Please let me know if you have any concerns but it seems to work :)

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE! For future googlers I strongly advise against this "workaround" and urge you to never copy a file to app/code/local to patch an issue. If you believe the problem needs to be addressed please contact the Magento core team by filing an issue against the Magento 2 repository at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues - better yet, issue this patch as a pull request against the M2 db.

Comment: Thanks for this, I wrote an extension that extends the Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate class to make this change without copying  the core file into local.

Answer (score 0):

I had to multiply the Taxable amount with Item Count to get the right result as below:

```
    if (Mage::helper('tax')->priceIncludesTax()) {
        $taxableAmount = 0;
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $taxableAmount += $item->getQty() * $item->getTaxableAmount();
        }
        $request->setPackageValue($taxableAmount);
    }
```